# Why is one of my CPP files not being built when using the command-line to compile

Tags: visual-studio, sybase-asa

The setup:
Windows XP
MS VisualStudio 2003
Sybase SQL Anywhere 9
Embedded SQL (I know...but it's a really old project)

This project is setup like so many others I have encountered here.  The SQL precompiler processes a SQC file to generate a CPP file which is then compiled into an OBJ and finally linked into part of the DLL.

When using the GUI dev environment, there is no problem.  The solution builds successfully every time, every machine.

When building from the command-line, the results seem to depend on the machine/environment.  In fact, I was able to successfully compile the project on the command-line successfully, initially.  Now, I too am having issues.

I have quadruple checked the paths.  And the settings.  It looks just like any other project with this type of setup.  The paths are valid.  I have admin rights to the entire system.  The generated file is not read-only or checked-in to the RCS.  When I clean, the files are removed including the CPP.  The CPP is not excluded from the build in the project.

From what I have found, the generated CPP file is created and located where it should be but doesn't get added to the compiler response file.  So the CPP is never built.  But the linker response file contains the OBJ in its listing.  Since the file does not exist because it was not compiled, it fails to link.

I've run out of ideas on what else could cause this issue.

The command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Common7\Tools\..\ide\devenv.com" C:\workspaces\Borg\Main\_build\..\BioID\BioID.sln /build Release /out C:\workspaces\Borg\Main\_build\..\_build\output\visualstudio.log
```

results in the following BuildLog.htm.  The paths are exactly as defined by our build script using nant so I can recreate the problem at will directly.

```
------- Build started: Project: PyxPosId, Configuration: Release|Win32 -------

 Command Lines      Creating temporary file "c:\workspaces\Borg\Main\BioID\Release\BAT000001.bat" with contents
[
@echo off
sqlpp -o WINNT -r "c:\workspaces\Borg\Main\BioID\SQLBIO.SQC" "c:\workspaces\Borg\Main\BioID\SQLBIO".cpp

if errorlevel 1 goto VCReportError
goto VCEnd
:VCReportError
echo Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Performing Custom Build Step"
exit 1
:VCEnd
]
Creating command line "c:\workspaces\Borg\Main\BioID\Release\BAT000001.bat"
Creating temporary file "c:\workspaces\Borg\Main\BioID\Release\RSP000002.rsp" with contents
[
/O2 /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "_WINDLL" /FD /EHsc /MT /YX"stdafx.h" /Fp".\PyxPosId___Win32_Release_Sybase9/BioId.pch" /Fo".\PyxPosId___Win32_Release_Sybase9/" /Fd".\PyxPosId___Win32_Release_Sybase9/" /W3 /c /TP
.\VXBio.cpp
.\VFSbio.cpp
.\VBioDlg.cpp
.\USTDREG.CPP
.\USTDNEW.CPP
.\STDREG.CPP
.\STDNEW.CPP
.\SetupConfigPage.cpp
.\SCCfgDlg.cpp
.\ScanId.cpp
.\pyxsheet.cpp
.\PyxPosId.cpp
.\MsgBox.cpp
.\FTbio.cpp
.\FIUBIO.CPP
.\DevTypePg.cpp
.\CGray8Dib.cpp
.\CardScan.cpp
.\bioutils.cpp
.\BioSet.cpp
.\BioDb.cpp
.\BIO.CPP
.\APPSRC.CPP
]
Creating command line "cl.exe @c:\workspaces\Borg\Main\BioID\Release\RSP000002.rsp /nologo"
Creating temporary file "c:\workspaces\Borg\Main\BioID\Release\RSP000003.rsp" with contents
[
/O2 /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "_WINDLL" /FD /EHsc /MT /Yc"stdafx.h" /Fp".\PyxPosId___Win32_Release_Sybase9/BioId.pch" /Fo".\PyxPosId___Win32_Release_Sybase9/" /Fd".\PyxPosId___Win32_Release_Sybase9/" /W3 /c /TP
.\StdAfx.cpp
]
Creating command line "cl.exe @c:\workspaces\Borg\Main\BioID\Release\RSP000003.rsp /nologo"
Creating command line "rc.exe /d "NDEBUG" /l 0x409 /fo"Release/BIO.res" .\BIO.RC"
Creating temporary file "c:\workspaces\Borg\Main\BioID\Release\RSP000004.rsp" with contents
[
/OUT:"PyxPosId___Win32_Release_Sybase9/Pyxposid.dll" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /DLL /NODEFAULTLIB:"libc.lib" /NODEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMTD" /DEF:".\PyxPosId.def" /DELAYLOAD:"OleAcc.dll" /PDB:".\PyxPosId___Win32_Release_Sybase9/Pyxposid.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /IMPLIB:".\PyxPosId___Win32_Release_Sybase9/Pyxposid.lib" /MACHINE:X86 NAFXCW.LIB  dblibtm.lib dpfpfns.lib dpmatch.lib  vxapi.lib DelayImp.lib DelayImp.lib
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\APPSRC.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\BIO.obj
.\Release\BIO.res
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\BioDb.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\BioSet.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\bioutils.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\CardScan.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\CGray8Dib.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\DevTypePg.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\FIUBIO.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\FTbio.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\MsgBox.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\PyxPosId.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\pyxsheet.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\ScanId.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\SCCfgDlg.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\SetupConfigPage.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\Sqlbio.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\StdAfx.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\STDNEW.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\STDREG.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\USTDNEW.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\USTDREG.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\VBioDlg.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\VFSbio.obj
.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\VXBio.obj
]
Creating command line "link.exe @c:\workspaces\Borg\Main\BioID\Release\RSP000004.rsp"
 Output Window      Performing Custom Build Step
Adaptive Server Anywhere Embedded SQL Version 9.0.2.3169
Using collation sequence "1252LATIN1"
c:/workspaces/Borg/Main/BioID/SQLBIO.SQC(715): Warning! W2665 near ';': host variable 'hvuserIid' has been redefined
Compiling...
StdAfx.cpp
 WINVER not defined. Defaulting to 0x0501 (Windows XP and Windows .NET Server)
Compiling...
VXBio.cpp
 WINVER not defined. Defaulting to 0x0501 (Windows XP and Windows .NET Server)
VXBio.cpp(818) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from '__time64_t' to 'time_t', possible loss of data
VFSbio.cpp
**OPTION** WIN32=Building for 32-bit Windows
VBioDlg.cpp
 WINVER not defined. Defaulting to 0x0501 (Windows XP and Windows .NET Server)
**OPTION** WIN32=Building for 32-bit Windows
USTDREG.CPP
 WINVER not defined. Defaulting to 0x0501 (Windows XP and Windows .NET Server)
**OPTION** WIN32=Building for 32-bit Windows
USTDNEW.CPP
**OPTION** WIN32=Building for 32-bit Windows
STDREG.CPP
 WINVER not defined. Defaulting to 0x0501 (Windows XP and Windows .NET Server)
**OPTION** WIN32=Building for 32-bit Windows
STDNEW.CPP
**OPTION** WIN32=Building for 32-bit Windows
SetupConfigPage.cpp
 WINVER not defined. Defaulting to 0x0501 (Windows XP and Windows .NET Server)
**OPTION** WIN32=Building for 32-bit Windows
SCCfgDlg.cpp
 WINVER not defined. Defaulting to 0x0501 (Windows XP and Windows .NET Server)
ScanId.cpp
pyxsheet.cpp
PyxPosId.cpp
MsgBox.cpp
FTbio.cpp
FIUBIO.CPP
 WINVER not defined. Defaulting to 0x0501 (Windows XP and Windows .NET Server)
FIUBIO.CPP(1456) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from '__time64_t' to 'time_t', possible loss of data
DevTypePg.cpp
 WINVER not defined. Defaulting to 0x0501 (Windows XP and Windows .NET Server)
CGray8Dib.cpp
CardScan.cpp
 WINVER not defined. Defaulting to 0x0501 (Windows XP and Windows .NET Server)
bioutils.cpp
 WINVER not defined. Defaulting to 0x0501 (Windows XP and Windows .NET Server)
BioSet.cpp
 WINVER not defined. Defaulting to 0x0501 (Windows XP and Windows .NET Server)
BioDb.cpp
BioDb.cpp(508) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from '__time64_t' to 'time_t', possible loss of data
BIO.CPP
 WINVER not defined. Defaulting to 0x0501 (Windows XP and Windows .NET Server)
**OPTION** WIN32=Building for 32-bit Windows
BIO.CPP(1202) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from '__time64_t' to 'time_t', possible loss of data
BIO.CPP(1319) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from '__time64_t' to 'time_t', possible loss of data
APPSRC.CPP
 WINVER not defined. Defaulting to 0x0501 (Windows XP and Windows .NET Server)
Compiling resources...
Linking...
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '.\pyxposid___win32_release_sybase9\Sqlbio.obj'
 Results      Build log was saved at "file://c:\workspaces\Borg\Main\BioID\Release\BuildLog.htm"
PyxPosId - 1 error(s), 5 warning(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there is a case sensitivity issue.  I stopped using `$(InputName)` and hard-coded the name in my vcproj to match everwhere.

Just so you are all aware, I'm not going to open a trouble ticket with MS for a 8 year old development environment.